# How do you check if MongoDB connection is alive in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

How do you check if MongoDB connection is alive using the latest 2.0 .NET MongoDB Driver? Please don't include solutions using the legacy driver. Thanks.

I used to use the Ping method but that may eventually become obsolete (placed in the Legacy dll since 2.0 release):
http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoServerInstance_Ping.htm

Comment: Oh come on, just read the documentation https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/

Comment: Sorry but I did not see anything on how to check if a connection is alive.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do.

1. You can check your MongoClient's Cluster.Description property which gives you an indication of the health of the entire cluster.
2. Alternatively, you can run the ping command manually. The problem with doing this is that it is only going to ping 1 server and if you are looking for health of the entire cluster, then.

   await client.GetDatabase("admin").RunCommandAsync(new BsonDocument("ping", 1))
3. Not worry about it. The driver is handling the situations where failover is happening and, in many cases, will wait for the failover to happen prior to running your operation.

Perhaps if you elaborated on your need, I could provide a better answer.

Comment: Personally, I just wanted to ping the server for a health check endpoint

Answer (score 0):

So after going through the documentation, i did not find anything equivalent to ping. The only other solution i see is to execute a simple operation and see if it fails. Try something like:

```
db.getName()
```

If that fails, you know the connection has been dropped.